# modifying bytes stream of a pdf

Tags: java, pdf, byte, pdfbox, bytestream

> I am receiving a byte stream by calling a rest endpoint which
>   represents a pdf, and this pdf is just a template with placeholders
>   for fields like firstName, lastName etc. Now I want to play with the
>   byte stream (convert to some object maybe?) and populate fields like
>   firstName, lastName and then convert the formatted thingy back to
>   bytestream and send to UI.

1. Is it even possible?
2. How to start with, is there any tool available for that? Like pdfbox

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, this is possible with PDFBox, if the fields are AcroForn fields. Yes PDFBox can read the byte stream, set the fields, and save it into a byte output stream. In the PDFBox source download, go to the directory org.apache.pdfbox.examples.interactive.form in the examples subproject.

Comment: Abhijeet, as you formulate your requirements, any decent general purpose pdf library should be usable.

Comment: @mkl Should I consider some expression languages, like apache jexl?

Comment: *"Should I consider some expression languages, like apache jexl"* - no, use a decent general purpose pdf library. E.g. PDFBox.

Comment: See this answer for how to fill forms. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29417945/535646 , assuming your forms are AcroForm and not XFA. Re "expression language", be aware that PDF isn't something like HTML. Open a PDF with a text editor and you'll understand.